# Optim function does not work as expected due to warnings message

Tags: r

I would like to write estimation function to estimate model parameters. I wrote my function without any error, however `optim` function does not work as expected. When I run my code line by line I found that my condition returns me `warnings` messages (`the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`). So, I think this is the problem that makes `optim` does not work as expected. That because, when I run my code line by line, I got this message and when I run `optim` function I got this:
`~Error in optim(par = start.parm, fn = t_LL, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = low,  : 
  object 'low' not found`

However, I am not sure.

Here is my code:

```
library(VineCopula)

simdata <– BiCopSim(300, 5, -2)
```

## I call my function like this:

`Myfun <- MLE(simdata, family = 5, par = -2, par2 = 0)`

```
MLE <- function(data, family, par,par2) {

  n <- dim(data)[1]
  start.parm <- c(par,par2)


if (family %in% c(3, 13)) {
  low <- 1e-04
  up <- 100
} else if (family %in% c(4, 14)) {
  low <- 1.0001
  up <- 100
} else if (family %in% c(5)) {
  low <- -100
  up <- 100
} 



t_LL <- function(param, family, start, start2) {
    start <- param[[1]]
    start2 <- param[[2]]
    ll <- sum(log(BiCopPDF(data[,1], data[,2], family, start, start2)))
    return(ll)
  }
optimout <- optim(par = start.parm,
                  fn = t_LL,
                  family= family,
                  start=start, 
                  start2=start2,
                  method = "L-BFGS-B",
                  lower = low,
                  upper = up,
                  control = list(fnscale = -1, maxit = 500))




out <- list()


      out$par <- optimout$par[1]




 out$value <- optimout$value
  out
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: You should show the call you're using. It looks like none of your conditions for `family` are met, so `low` and `up` never get assigned.

Comment: As to the warning you're getting, sounds like you are passing a vector argument to `family`, but the `if` blocks you are using expect a condition of length 1.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Thanks so much for your comments. However, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila I call low and up inside `optim` function.

Comment: I meant the call to `MLE`. You're passing an `family` argument that your function doesn't know how to deal with.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila I updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: The example that you provided runs fine for me? The problem that you're having in your real case is that you're passing a vector argument to `family`, only its first value gets used for the `if` block, it doesn't match any of the values you check for, and as a result `low` and `up` don't get assigned. If you want to be able to pass a vector argument `family`, take a look at `ifelse` to replace your `if` block. If not, throw an error if `length(family) > 1` and add an `else` to your `if` block to throw an error if the given `family` doesn't match any of your choices.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Your comment work. Could you please pass it as an answer. The first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're having in your real case is that you're: 1) passing a vector argument to `family`; 2) only its first value gets used for the `if` block; 3) it doesn't match any of the values you check for; and 4) as a result `low` and `up` don't get assigned.

If you want to be able to pass a vector argument `family`, take a look at `ifelse` to replace your `if` block. If not, throw an error if `length(family) > 1` and add an `else` to your `if` block to throw an error if the given `family` doesn't match any of your choices.